# Bootstrap typeahead in a popover

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, typeahead.js

I am trying to implement bootstrap's typeahead but I am trying to have the input bar appear on a popover when a button is click.

Pretty much have a typeahead functionality inside a popover.

```
<div id="popover-button-container">
    <button id="popover-button" type="button" class="btn btn-default" 
            data-toggle="popover"
            data-placement="left">${entries.size() - 4} more</button>
            <div id="popover-content" class="hide">
                <input class="typeahead" type="text" placeholder="Search by Artist Name" />
            </div>
</div>
```

Adding the JS:

```
<script>
$("#popover-button").popover({
    html:true,
    content: function(){
        return $('#popover-content').html();
    }
})</script>
```

The typeahead doesnt seem to work in the popover however. If I remove the class=hide part, the unhidden input works but not the one in the popover.

Wondering if anyone has ran into this?

Any help would be great!

Comment: please show us your JS

Comment: added the js for popover

Answer (score 0):

did you try this?

```
// Constructs the suggestion engine
// Typehead codes here

$('#myPopover').on('show.bs.popover', function () {

  // Initialize your typehead script
  typehead.initilize();

  // Followed by your Typehead codes here...

})
```

Comment: Hey sorry! I will try this out and give you an update. Havent had time today :(